# How can I Bookmark VBA DAO recordset items so that I can group them for processing?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to treat records in the recordset as their own group so they can be processed.

I'm working with email addresses of each record as the primary identifier of each person and there are many duplicates of that email address in the original dataset with different row values.
I need to consolidate the data across all fields for that email address, so five records becomes one.

Example:

```
Bob Person | Bob@gmail.com | 555-555-5555 | A, B  (I want to bookmark)
Tess Jones | TJ@gmail.com  | 555-115-5555 | 1, C  (Get on the next iteration)
Bob Person | Bob@gmail.com | 555-555-5555 | 1, C  (I want to bookmark)
Bob Person | Bob@gmail.com | 555-555-5555 | 1, B  (I want to bookmark)
Bob Person | Bob@gmail.com | 555-555-5555 | A, B  (I want to bookmark)
```

Becomes:

```
Bob Person | Bob@gmail.com | 555-555-5555 | 1, A, B, C
```

Once bookmarked I need to develop code which can do this, but the bookmarking part is throwing me off.  What will I add the bookmarked records to... an array perhaps?

```vb
Dim rst as DAO.recordset
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim CurrentEmail as String

Dim RecorsetSQL = "SELECT Name, Email, Info Phone FROM TableName"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordSet(RecorsetSQL)
set db = CurrentDB

Do Until rst.EOF
    CurrentEmail = rst!Email
    rst.MoveNext
    
    If CurrentEmail = rst!Email Then
        THIS RECORD = tagged
        'I'd like to bookmark any and all records that meet this criteria as I cycle through them, so that I can manipulate them

Loop

Get all bookmarks where bookmarks = tagged
```

Comment: How do you expect to 'bookmark' a record - set a yes/no field in table?

Comment: DAO Recordsets have a bookmark property for various records.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-bookmark-property-dao

Comment: You have a single field with comma-separated values of "A, B", etc? Combining those values from multiple records requires VBA and CSV adds complication, review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: I was planning on just adding them to an array or collection, and then culling the array/collection of duplicates.  I guess rather than bookmarking the records I could just add them to an array.

Comment: Yes. Use a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with a database, I suggest a different approach, using an outer + inner loop.

**Outer loop**: all unique emails:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM TableName
```

**Inner loop** for all persons with the current email, this loop runs twice:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Email = <outerEmail>
```

**1st run:** collect all data you want to consolidate

**2nd run:**
First record: update with consolidated data (`rst.Edit + rst.Update`)
All other records: `rst.Delete`

Comment: Are you suggesting using a recordset here?

Comment: Two recordsets, for outer and inner loop. @Picayuni